# Error importing node modules in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I had a problem this morning that was driving me crazy.  I'll explain the issue and then I'll provide my answer below (so that others who come across this can get to a solution sooner).

It is very easy to duplicate the issue by just issuing these commands:

```
tsd query react --action install
mkdir src
echo "import React = require('react');" > src/foo.ts
```

I also included the following `tsconfig.json` file in `src`:

```
{
    "version": "1.6.2",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./tsdir",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "files": [
        "foo.ts"
    ]
}
```

If I try to compile this by simply running the `tsc` (version 1.6.2) command inside `src`, I get:

```
foo.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react'.
```

What I find baffling here is that I've installed the `react` bindings with `tsd` but when I run `tsc`, I get this error.  It looks like I've done everything right, so why the error?

Answer (score 0):

So what I eventually figured out was that I need to explicitly include the `typings` file in my list of `"files"`, i.e.,

```
{
    "version": "1.6.2",
    "compilerOptions": {
       ...
    },
    "files": [
        "foo.ts",
        "../typings/react/react.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

In other words, I had to include the `typings` files explicitly in the `"files"`.  I don't really know why.  I thought `tsc` was smart enough to look for them itself.

**If there is a better solution that doesn't involve having to list all the `.d.ts` files explicitly in `"files"`, I'm all ears**.  But I just wanted to point out that this is at least a workaround.